# Delete button showing up as the word "delete" rather than the normal X

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, deleted-comments, deletion

Just now, when I went to delete one of my comments, I noticed the normal "X" to delete it was replaced by the actual word "delete":

[image]

Is this a bug? If not, why was it changed?

Comment: status-by-design: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7527074#7527074

Comment: @rene do you know why it was changed?

Comment: This needs less designers, fits better in the [Stacks design](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks) and offers better accessibility and translate-ability. I have no idea why it was changed.

Comment: The `(X)` was much less obtrusive than the flashing red `"Delete"` on mouseover. I hope you will reconsider. This seems like a step backwards in usability from a human-factors standpoint. At least just have it show up and turn red when I mouseover that area, not the entire comment. `"Edit"` doesn't jump off the page at you like `"Delete"` now does.

Comment: Asked on Meta.SE: [Why was the comment delete button changed from the X icon to the word “Delete”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323292/289905).

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why is https://stackoverflow.design publicly accessible?

Comment: It might not have been a design goal but I imagine people might be more likely to clean up their own obsolete comments with the new design

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There were two scenarios where the action was already marked with text instead of that little icon:

1. If you had the mobile theme active (also, both delete and edit would always be visible)
2. There was a separate, empty link with the title "delete this comment" that would never be hidden and thus would be accessible to screen reading software.

Both were a bit awkward though; #1 didn't help if you *weren't* using the mobile theme (say, because you prefer the new responsive theme for your mobile device). #2 was a straight-up hack that [left a big gap in accessibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320571/cant-edit-a-comment-without-the-mouse).

Also, apparently Mobile Safari hated everything about this, while other mobile browsers blithely let you tap and trigger edits or deletion via links you couldn't even see; definitely not ideal for those of us with clumsy fingers!

The new design goes beyond just making the image into a text link; it allows keyboard navigation, better accessibility, and a reasonable mobile experience without having to switch themes. For more details, see Brian's answer to: [Can't edit a comment without the mouse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320571/cant-edit-a-comment-without-the-mouse/323283#323283)